# Angularjs filter date in ng-init

Tags: angularjs

I have date I want to break it into day, month, year.

**Code**

```
//$date=1983-05-10

     <select name="selectedDay" ng-init="basic.selectedDay=10">
```

How to get number 10 in `ng-init`.

Thank you.

Comment: `var dob=basic.selectedDay;var splitDate = dob.split('/');var convertedDate=new Date(splitDate[2], splitDate[1]-1, splitDate[0]);` please check it

Comment: Im sorry but it look way to many code for a simple thing. If angular not provide any short way then. I would find other way.

Comment: That $date sent from controller? and do you want to set a value to your select option? can you please improve your question with more details?